# Updated Ionic CLI but shows previous version (Windows)

Tags: npm, ionic-framework

I want to update the Ionic CLI tool to the latest version (v1.3.13).
I do this:

```
npm update -g ionic
```

It appears to work.  No errors, it gets all the files successfully.

But - I do this:

```
ionic --version
```

And it shows the previous version!  Why?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I had installed Ionic last year, but locally.
I had installed it in C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Nodejs directory.

I removed these files from this directory:

- ionic
- ionic.cmd

And this folder in the \node-modules directory:

- ionic

Once I did this, when I ran the command,

```
ionic --version
```

...it displayed the correct version, due to it being successfully installed in the global space (AppData\Roaming\npm).

Hope this helps other Windows users.

Answer (score 2):

inject this line of code in your project in bower.json file and run `bower update`

```
"ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.1.0",
```