# Cannot start an ionic 2 blank project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to start an ionic 2 blank project but it always create an ionic 1 project. That's what I do:

```
npm install -g ionic@beta
ionic start Test --v2
```

but when I open the project it's still version 1. I have tried to remove ionic completely with:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic@beta
sudo npm uninstall -g cordova
```

but after that when I type "ionic" it's showing that I have ionic v1.7.14. (did it several times and there aren't any errors).

Comment: Try with this command `ionic start MyIonic2Project blank --v2`

Comment: I've just tried but it's the same...

Comment: Type `ionic serve` where you created the project and see the console logs

Comment: ----------------------------------------------------------------
Running live reload server: undefined
Watching: 0=www/**/*, 1=!www/lib/**/*
Running dev server:  ******

ionic $ serve  /?ionicplatform=ios  (www/index.html)
serve  /?ionicplatform=android  (www/index.html)
serve  /css/style.css
serve  /lib/ionic/css/ionic.css
serve  /lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js
serve  /cordova.js  (mocked)
serve  /js/app.js

Comment: nothing strange... Like with all others projects. I do not have any errors.

Comment: Try with `sudo npm install -g ionic@beta` again

Comment: I've tried several times. Nothing changes. I even remove node and npm and installed them again. Even when I remove ionic completely with 
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic@beta
sudo npm uninstall -g cordova

It's still there

Comment: I have this same problem... did you ever fix it?

Comment: @Harangue did you try with ionic start Example -v2?

Comment: I was also facing same issue like you, but following helped me [Answer by J](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28904697)

Answer (score 6):

for a blank project you can give the following command

```
ionic start ProjectName blank --v2
```

for tabs template you can give

```
ionic start ProjectName tabs --v2
```

--v2 is for ionic 2 project

you can also include --ts for getting the typescript project

```
ionic start ProjectName blank --v2 --ts
```

Answer (score 2):

As of now The --v1 and --v2 flags have been removed.

ionic 1 blank project

> ionic start myapp blank --type ionic1

ionic 2 blank project

> ionic start myApp blank

ionic 3 blank project

> ionic start myapp blank --type ionic-angular

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found what was wrong. In the documentation it's written:

```
ionic start Example --v2
```

where it should be (at least in my case)

```
ionic start Example -v2
```

Answer (score 0):

Best tutorial follow the below link
First of install  latest Node 6 LTS and NPM 3+ in window machinne.

/>npm install -g ionic@latest

/>ionic start mySampleApp

/>cd ./mySampleApp

/>npm install -g cordova

For android
/>ionic cordova  platform add android

For ios
/>ionic cordova platform add ios

/>ionic cordova run android

That’s all if any error or problem comes please comment below.

http://infiniteneed.com/setup-and-start-ionic-mobile-app-from-scratch-in-window-machine/

Answer (score -2):

I believe you will also need ionic@beta - currently 2.0.19

```
npm install -g ionic@beta
```

The great thing is, you can still use this CLI to install/control/build Ionic@1.x apps - in fact, there's little difference to the user since Ionic v1 is still the default for `ionic@beta`.

Comment: As I described above I use npm install -g ionic@beta